# What is the differences between "-genvall" and "-envall"?

Tags: mpi, intel-mpi

When I need to pass my environment variables in my mpi job, what is the differences between "-genvall" and "-envall" options? I really cannot understand the description in man file.

Comment: This is implementation specific. Please specify which MPI implementation you use.

Comment: @Zulan , I use Intel MPI.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://docs.par-tec.com/html/psmpi-userguide/rn01re01.html

you will see

> -genvall 
>   Export all environment variables to all processes. Same as --envall.

So there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, in the man file from Intel, their descriptions are different. For "-genvall", it is "Use this option to enable propagation of all environment variables to all MPI processes." For "-envall", it is "Use this option to propagate all environment variables in the current argument set."  I don't think they are exactly the same but cannot tell the differences.